# Constructor method for particular parameter

Tags: java, constructor, initialization, private

I am trying to have this data field:

*The actual size of the collection, initially zero. It should not exceed the preset limit at any moment.*

And this constructor:

*Given a parameter specifying the limit on the collection size, an empty book collection is created using the given parameter. The parameter should not exceed the preset maximum size 200.*

I keep getting the instructions switched up, but right now I am not sure how to pass this parameter specifying the 'limit' on the collection size, and then make an empty book collection(BookCollection is my class).

Here is my code:

```
public class BookCollection{

   //data fields, need complete
   private int limit = 200;
   //Array of type book
   private int Book[];

   //actual size of collection, initialized to zero. Must never exceed limit
   private int collection[];

   //Constructor
   public BookCollection(int l, int c){
      collection = c[];
      limit = l;
      BookCollection[] collection = new BookCollection[200];   //initialize array of 200     
      }
    }
```

***How do I specifically follow that instruction for the parameter passing?*** Right now I am passing in my private limit of 200, and the collection. And also, in my initialization of collection, isn't this auto-initialized to zero? ***So I do not have to set the initialization to zero like the first data field instruction?***

**I THINK I SOLVED IT BELOW**

```
/*
* BookCollection.java
*
*/

public class BookCollection{

   //data fields, need complete
   private int limit = 200;
   //Array of type book
   private int Book[];

   //actual size of collection, initialized to zero. Must never exceed limit
   private int collection[];

   //Constructor
   public BookCollection(int l){
      limit = l;
      BookCollection[] collection = new BookCollection[limit];   //initialize array of 200     
      }
}
```

Anyway, if anyone has input on if I did anything wrong let me know :) Otherwise I'll mark this as corrected in a bit here.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors do not return anything. So remove `void` from

```
   public void BookCollection(int l, int c)
```

and define it like

```
   public BookCollection(int l, int c)
```